# How to get emails from only a particular email address in Outlook REST API?

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I have a manual from Outlook Dev - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#GetMessages

But they do not tell how to get emails from one particular email address..

How can I add this filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following api:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages$search=%22from:testuser@testdomain.com%22")
```